# $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0$ exact, $M''$ flat. Why is $M$ flat $\Leftrightarrow M'$ flat?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let
>   \begin{align}
> 0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0
> \end{align}
>   be an exact sequence of $A$-modules with $M''$ flat.
>
> **I want to show:** $M$ flat $\Leftrightarrow M'$ flat.

However, I don't manage to show this. I try to use the fact that $M / M'$ is isomorphic to the flat module $M''$, but I don't know how this helps. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, use only the definition of flatness and the nine lemma (or make the diagram chase just for fun!).

Comment: @YACP Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $N' \to N$ is a monomorphism, we have a commutative diagram:

$\begin{array}{c} & & & & & &  0 & \\ &&&&&& \downarrow \\ 0 & \rightarrow & M' \otimes N' & \rightarrow & M \otimes N' & \rightarrow & M'' \otimes N' & \rightarrow & 0 \\ && \downarrow && \downarrow &&\downarrow && \\0 & \rightarrow & M' \otimes N & \rightarrow & M \otimes N & \rightarrow & M'' \otimes N & \rightarrow & 0\end{array}$

The rows and columns are exact because $M''$ is flat. The Snake Lemma yields an exact sequence
$$0 \to \ker(M' \otimes N' \to M' \otimes N) \to \ker(M \otimes N' \to M \otimes N) \to 0,$$

and the claim follows. This proof works in a quite general setting, namely in so-called tame abelian $\otimes$-categories. See Jacob Lurie's *Tannaka duality for geometric stacks*, Lemma 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

Use the homological characterization of flatness and the long exact sequence of homology for Tor.